# Tengo este problemas en xampp: Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Buen día, estoy intentando acceder a mi carpeta htdocs en Xampp desde mi navegador para ver mis programas php que tengo dentro de la carpeta llamada `Programas`, pero no he podido siempre que ingreso al local host desde mi puerto 8080 que tengo configurado solo me arroja esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`**Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.**`

`Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/7.3.26 Server at localhost Port 8080`

Lo raro es que puedo acceder a mi phpmyadmin sin problema: en mysql tengo el puerto 3307 y en apache el 8080 y 443 por defecto y se conectan correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra cosa que observe es que si intento acceder a mi localhost en 127.0.0.1 no me permite aparece esto:

`**No se puede acceder a este sitio web La página 127.0.0.1 ha rechazado la conexión. Prueba a: Comprobar la conexión Comprobar el proxy y el cortafuegos ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**`